# How to add some prefix to every rule in mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a lot of rules in mod_rewrite. For now we decide to add a second language to our website. So is there any way to add some prefix to every rule if there is one in url? for example i have next rules:

```
RewriteRule ^addorder/?$ add_order.php
RewriteRule ^order/?$ order.php
```

so if i have next link http://test.com/addorder/ than i should go to

```
RewriteRule ^addorder/?$ add_order.php
```

and if i have next link http://test.com/en/addorder/ than i should go to

```
RewriteRule ^addorder/?$ add_order.php?lang=en
```

and as i said i dont want to duplicate rules like this, because there is a lot of them

```
RewriteRule ^addorder/?$ add_order.php
RewriteRule ^/en/addorder/?$ add_order.php?lang=en
RewriteRule ^order/?$ order.php
RewriteRule ^/en/order/?$ order.php?lang=en
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid repeating similar rules by taking care of `lang` component first in a separate rule without `L` flag:

```
RewriteEngine On

# handle lang parameter (this rule will be followed by rules below)
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.+)$ $2?lang=$1 [QSA]

# specific rules to corresponding .php files
RewriteRule ^addorder/?$ add_order.php [L,NC]

# generic catch all .php handler for order -> order.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```